# Is every nonzero submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$ (as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module) essential?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is every nonzero submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$ (as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module) essential?

My knowledges:

For a $K$ submodule of $M$ is essential in case,

For every submodule of $M$, $K\cap L=0$ implies $L=0$

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules = subgroups. A non-zero subgroup is of the form $n \mathbb{Z}$ for some $n \ne 0$.

Comment: So if I take $K=n\mathbb{Z}$ and $L=m\mathbb{Z}$. I can say if $K\cap L=0$ then $L=0$. Because of $K\cap L=$lcm(n,m)$\mathbb{Z}$